# Wildcard input causes other search inputs to retrieve all data in multiple input search form

Tags: mysql, search, pdo, prepared-statement, wildcard

I have a multi field php search form. When a wildcard is added to one of the search fields, it causes the other fields to retrieve all of the data in the database. Without the wildcard, **country** finds only countries and **cityname** finds only cities:

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM `epic_schools_tbl` WHERE ";

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) { 

   if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
      $country = $_POST['country'];
      $sql .= " `country` = :country ";
   }
   if (isset($_POST['cityname'])) {
      $cityname = $_POST['cityname'];
      $sql .= " OR `city` = :cityname ";
   }
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute(array($country,$cityname));

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<p>" . $row['country'] . "</p><p>" . $row['city'] . "</p>" . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

When the wild card (**schoolname**) is added:

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM `epic_schools_tbl` WHERE ";

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) { 

   if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
       $country = $_POST['country'];
       $sql .= " `country` = :country ";
   }
   if (isset($_POST['schoolname'])) {
       $schoolname = $_POST['schoolname'];
       $sql .= " OR `school_name` LIKE :schoolname ";
   }
   if (isset($_POST['cityname'])) {
       $cityname = $_POST['cityname'];
       $sql .= " OR `city` = :cityname ";
   }
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute(array($country,"%$schoolname%",$cityname));

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<p>" . $row['country'] . "</p><p>" . $row['school_name'] . "</p><p>" . $row['city'] . "</p>" . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

it causes **country** and or **cityname** to retrieve all of the data in the database. Can the SELECT statement be written to accept one input with a wildcard with other inputs in the form that are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the solution to the problem included putting an IF function inside the select statement. Also, replacing OR with AND helped to eliminate the city field or the schoolname field from returning the entire database if left blank.

```
$sql = "select * from epic_schools_tbl where country = if(length(:countryname)=0, country, :countryname2) and city = if(length(:cityname)=0, city, :cityname2) and (school_name like concat('%', if(length(:schoolname)=0, school_name, :schoolname2) , '%') or alternate_names like concat('%', if(length(:alternatenames)=0, alternate_names, :alternatenames2) , '%') and aka_names like concat('%', if(length(:akanames)=0, aka_names, :akanames2) , '%'))";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$countryname = $_POST['country'];
$cityname = $_POST['cityname'];
$schoolname = $_POST['schoolname'];
$alternatenames = $_POST['schoolname'];
$akanames = $_POST['schoolname'];

//Bind the variables to the prepared statement. Maybe each bind variable must have unique name.
$stmt->bindParam(':countryname', $countryname);
$stmt->bindParam(':countryname2', $countryname);
$stmt->bindParam(':cityname', $cityname);
$stmt->bindParam(':cityname2', $cityname);
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolname', $schoolname);   
$stmt->bindParam(':schoolname2', $schoolname); 
$stmt->bindParam(':alternatenames', $alternatenames);   
$stmt->bindParam(':alternatenames2', $alternatenames);
$stmt->bindParam(':akanames', $akanames);   
$stmt->bindParam(':akanames2', $akanames);

//Nothing to pass in. Everything is already bound.  
$stmt->execute();
```